# How to make SQL query to sort data of the same kind from two column in a table and select from the query

Tags: sql

I have a table that has two column that contain similar data, but I want to check the two column col1 and col2, if the number of data in col1 is equal to number of data col2, make a temp list of col1 data that has lesser number of data in col2.
my table is like this.

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 0001 | 0000 |
| 0002 | 0001 |
| 0003 | 0001 |
| 0004 | 0002 |
| 0005 | 0002 |
| 0006 | 0003 |
| 0007 | 0004 |
| 0008 | 0005 |

so I want to check col1 against col2, any data in col2 that is less than 2 will be listed on a temporal list, then from the temporal list I will like to select any number of row.

Please anyone with Idea on how I can solve this.
Thanks.

Edited.
My expected result is:

| Col1 | Col2 | temp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 0000 | null |
| 0002 | 0001 | null |
| 0003 | 0001 | 0003 |
| 0004 | 0002 | 0004 |
| 0005 | 0002 | 0005 |
| 0006 | 0003 | 0006 |
| 0007 | 0004 | 0007 |
| 0008 | 0005 | 0008 |

Then I can now select from temp col.

Comment: If the columns are in the same table you'll always have equal "numbers of data" assuming you mean equal rows unless you're possibly filling in NULLS for either column and you don't want to count those.

Comment: Also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: Table is not a spreadsheet. The data in a table is a set of rows, all rows contain the same number of columns.

Comment: Do you mean temp should be null if Col1 <= 2?

Comment: Yes. where Col1 appears two in Col2, temp should be null. as shown in my expected result table above.

Answer (score 0):

If I understad you right... Here is some Oracle SQL:

```
With data (col1, col2) as(Select '0001', '0000' from dual union all
Select '0002', '0001' from dual union all
Select '0003', '0001' from dual union all
Select '0004', '0002' from dual union all
Select '0005', '0002' from dual union all
Select '0006', '0003' from dual union all
Select '0007', '0004' from dual union all
Select '0008', '0005' from dual)
select col1
,col2 
,case when to_number(col1)-to_number(col2)<2 then null else col1 end col3
from data;
```